# How to control /etc/hosts file from over writing

Tags: linux, kubernetes, debian, debian-jessie

I am deploying a Kops Kubernetes cluster on AWS with Debian Jessie image.

Mine is a hybrid environment where my artifactory is in a physical env in our DC. Now I have been facing an issue, my worker nodes are unable to pull images from my artifactory unless I specify the artifactory FQDN and IP in the /etc/hosts file.

So this is a manual edit, it works all fine after I do this. So I went ahead and added the data in my additional `userdata` of the Kops worker node group, but I am seeing after some time the hosts file on worker nodes is getting overwritten and also this is evident upon node reboot.

So how can I resolve this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *real* answer is to run your own DNS server, or at least use DNS hostnames to resolve. If your router supports it, you can set local hostnames (machine-1.local)

If that isn't possible, you could try a solution like [puppet](https://puppet.com/) if you own the virtual machines. Also, I believe Kubernetes does have a DNS addon. Also, you could use a crontab for on boot to write to the hosts file, but that's a dirty solution.

In addition, your hosts file would get rewritten for every DHCP renew. You could use static IPs, but again, DNS is the way to go.

Comment: The question specifies AWS, and so I'd recommend Route 53 as a DNS service that you already have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for this is to put it in your [`/etc/rc.local`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49626/purpose-and-typical-usage-of-etc-rc-local) file:

If the file exists add this to the end:

```
echo '<ip-address-of-artifactory> <fqdn-of-artifactory>' >> /etc/hosts
```

If the file doesn't exist, create it:

```
$ cat << EOF > /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
#
echo '<ip-address-of-artifactory> <fqdn-of-artifactory>' >> /etc/hosts
EOF
$ chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
$ reboot # check that it works
```

Comment: This did not worked,, i think some process over writed this as wel,,,